# Custom ListView in Android with icon and text not working

Tags: android, list, listview, text, icons

im not expert in Java/Android but im still working on it.

I just wanted to know you to make custom ListView with Icon and Text.

list (listView1) is that ListView where i want icons...

Here's my code:

```
list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            R.layout.custom,
            R.id.app_name,
            listItems);
    list.setAdapter(adapter);

    list2 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView2); adapter2 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, listItems2); list2.setAdapter(adapter2);

    Directory directory = new Directory(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()); File[] files = directory.getFiles("*.apk", true);
    for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
        String apkPath = files[i].getPath() + files[i].getName();
        listItems2.add(apkPath); adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
        PackageInfo    pi = pm.getPackageArchiveInfo(apkPath, 0);
        pi.applicationInfo.sourceDir       = apkPath;
        pi.applicationInfo.publicSourceDir = apkPath;
        String AppName = (String)pi.applicationInfo.loadLabel(pm);
        //Drawable APKicon = pi.applicationInfo.loadIcon(pm);

        //<Here i get error when i try to change icon.>
        ImageView icon = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.app_icon);
        icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.about);
        //<>

        listItems.add(AppName);
    }
```

and here's my 'custom.xml' code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:orientation="horizontal" >

<ImageView android:id="@+id/app_icon" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />
<TextView android:id="@+id/app_name" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_centerVertical="true" android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/app_icon" android:text="" android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Please post your full code.

Comment: Please post the error here.

Comment: check [this](http://intransitione.com/blog/advanced-listview-populating-a-list-with-images-and-text/) tutorial.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, to understand better how to implement a custom listview, i advise you check this [tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/article.html). Now, looking for your problem. The first problem arrive because you are using ArrayAdapter to make a dynamic list. Take a look on that explanation retrived from the tutorial.

> **Input for ArrayAdapter**
>   The ArrayAdapter class can handle any Java object as input. It maps the data of this input to a TextView in the layout. You can define one in the constructor otherwise the android.R.id.text1 ID will be used.
>
> ArrayAdapter uses the toString() method of the data input object to determine the String which should be displayed.
>
> **Add and remove data**
>   The ArrayAdapter class allows to remove all elements in its underlying data structure with the clear() method call. You can then add new elements via the add() method or a Collection via the addAll() method.
>
> You can also directly modify the underlying data structure and call the notifyDataSetChanged() method on the adapter to notify him about the changes in data.
>
> **Warning**
>   If you want to change the data in your adapter the underlying data structure must support this operation. This is for example the case for the ArrayList class but not for arrays.

So, your first problem is, you are changing/filling your array after set it on your adapter. You should change this.

About put a icon on each line. To do this, you must write a custom adapter. For example, you can extends a custom a adapter to do that.

Again, retrived from the tutorial.

> **Developing a custom Adapter**
>   To control the data assignment and to support this assignment to several Views, you create your own Adapter implementation. For this you would extend an existing adapter implementations or by sub-classing the BaseAdapter class directly.
>
> ListView calls the getView() method on the adapter for each data element. In this method the adapter determines the layout of the row and how the data is mapped to the Views in this layout.
>
> This root of the layout is typically a ViewGroup (LayoutManager) and contains several other Views, e.g. an ImageView and a TextView.

So, the code below, implements a custom listView. On each line we have two textview and on icon. Take a look(You can sse the full example [here(Example CustomListView)](https://github.com/androidzin/android-examples)):

Result:

[image: Final Result]

list_layout.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:orientation="vertical"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent">

 <ListView android:id="@android:id/list" android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent" android:background="#EEEEEE"/>

 <TextView android:id="@android:id/empty" android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:background="#0000FF"
 android:text="@string/list_is_empty"/>  

</LinearLayout>
```

two_line_icon.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:orientation="horizontal"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent">

  <ImageView android:id="@+id/icon" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

 <LinearLayout 
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:orientation="vertical"
  >

    <TextView android:id="@+id/text1" android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Texto 1"/>

<TextView android:id="@+id/text2" android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Descricao"/>

 </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

ListWithIcon.java

```
public class ListWithIcon extends ListActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.list_layout);

    String[] dados = {"Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3",
            "Item 4", "Item 5", "Item 6", "Item 7"};

    String[] dados2 = {"desc 1", "desc 2", "desc 3",
            "desc 4", "desc 5", "desc 6", "desc 7"};

    MyAdapter myAdapter = new MyAdapter(this, dados, dados2); 

    setListAdapter(myAdapter);
}

@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
    Toast.makeText(this, l.getItemAtPosition(position).toString(),
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

}

MyAdapter.java

```
public class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private String[] data;
private String[] data2;
private Context context;

public MyAdapter(Context context, String[] data1, String[] data2) {
    super();
    this.data = data1;
    this.data2 = data2;
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return data.length;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return data[position];
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View rowView = LayoutInflater.from(context).
            inflate(R.layout.two_line_icon, parent, false);

    TextView text1 = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.text1);
    TextView text2 = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.text2);
    ImageView icon = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.icon);

    text1.setText(data[position]);
    text2.setText(data2[position]);
    icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);

    return rowView;
}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

its simple to implement. its working fine in myside.
Hope it will help you.

create the xml file : checklist.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
     android:id="@+id/listLayout"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
     android:layout_width="match_parent" 
     android:orientation="vertical">
 <LinearLayout  
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:orientation="horizontal"
 >
  <TextView android:id="@+id/listTitle" 
       android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
       android:layout_height="40dip" 
       android:textColor="#4E4E4E"
       android:layout_gravity="left"
       android:gravity="center_vertical"
       android:paddingLeft="5dip"
       android:singleLine="true"
       android:ellipsize="end"
       android:textSize="15sp"
     />    
   <LinearLayout 
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:gravity="right"
       android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
       android:layout_marginRight="5dip"
       >
     <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/listIcon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/arrow_for_list" >
    </ImageView>          
   </LinearLayout>

  </LinearLayout>
 <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:background="#DEDEDE"
 ></LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

NOw create the java class for listview.

LazyAdapter.java

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.text.Layout;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import com.nepotech.android.tld.R;

public class LazyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Activity activity;
    private String[] itemList;
    private static LayoutInflater inflater=null;

    public LazyAdapter(Activity a,String[] il) {
        fromQueue = 0;
        activity = a;
        itemList = il;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater)activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }   

    public int getCount() {
        return itemList.length;
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public static class ViewHolder{
        public TextView textList;
     }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View vi=convertView;
        ViewHolder holder;
        if(convertView==null){
                vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.checklist, null);


            holder.textList=(TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.listTitle);

            vi.setTag(holder);
        }
        else
            holder=(ViewHolder)vi.getTag();

            holder.textList.setText(itemList[position]);        

        return vi;
    }
}
```

Finally in you mainactivity call the lazyadapter like this :

here is the Activity named HomeActivity.java in my case.

```
    ListView listHome = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.check_list);
    LazyAdapter checkList_adapter = new LazyAdapter(HomeActivity.this,checkListArray,listArray);// where listArray is the String[] containing listing items in listview.
   listHome.setAdapter(checkList_adapter);
```

and in your main_activity xml add the the listview as you desire for example :.

```
<ListView
android:id="@+id/check_list"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:scrollbars="none"
android:fadingEdge="none"
android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector"
android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
>   
</ListView>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement custom adapter in case you are displaying different images in each and every row. Till then, you can start learning to implement this with this links:

http://www.javasrilankansupport.com/2012/05/android-listview-example-with-image-and.html

http://theopentutorials.com/tutorials/android/listview/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text-using-arrayadapter/

Comment: Thanks, the *2nd* link helped me a little bit! :D